# Rails - Deeply nested_attributes - Not recorded in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I encounter some issues regarding the recording of 3 nested_attributes_for in the database.

In my app, i have 3 models : Deal, Pool, Facility

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :pools, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pools, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :deal
has_many :facilities, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :facilities, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :pool
has_many :facilityschedules, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :facilityschedules, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Here is my Deal controller new action :

```
  def new
@deal = Deal.new
1.times do
  pool = @deal.pools.build
    1.times { pool.facilities.build }
end
end
```

here are my deal_params in the deal controller :

```
def deal_params
  params.require(:deal).permit(:name, pools_attributes: [:id, :name, :number, :deal_id, :_destroy, facilities_attributes: [:id, :name, :pool_id, :_destroy, ]])
end
```

EDIT :
Here is the message in rails console :

```
Started POST "/deals" for ::1 at 2016-01-12 21:19:26 +0100
Processing by DealsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"s3CQBTaa3lo/dzYDQKdKjs4XcE3HLSDYm/B6QjVi9JKns4x4LRjYKRQ4Fc+r4clyWQcrgmGrgrHsSGFtUEkwjg==", "deal"=>{"name"=>"Deal 26", "pools_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Pool 26", "_destroy"=>"0"}}, "facilities"=>{"name"=>"Facility 26", "_destroy"=>"0"}}, "commit"=>"Create Deal"}
Unpermitted parameter: facilities
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "deals" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Deal 26"], ["created_at", "2016-01-12 20:19:26.986981"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-12 20:19:26.986981"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "pools" ("name", "deal_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Pool 26"], ["deal_id", 21], ["created_at", "2016-01-12 20:19:26.988843"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-12 20:19:26.988843"]]
   (1.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/deals/21
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

It seems that facilities are unhautorized paramterers. How can i change that?
Here is my view form :

```
    <%= form_for(@deal) do |f| %>
  <% if @deal.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@deal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this deal from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @deal.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>



  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, "Deal name"%>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <br/>
  </div>


<div>
  <%= f.fields_for :pools do |builder|%>
  <%= builder.label :name, "Pool name" %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name, :rows => 3 %>
  <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= builder.label :_destroy, "Remove Pool" %>
  <br/>
  <% end %>
 </div>

 <div>
  <%= f.fields_for :facilities do |builder|%>
  <%= builder.label :name, "Facility name" %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name, :rows => 3 %>
  <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= builder.label :_destroy, "Remove Facility" %>
  <br/>
  <% end %>
 </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>


<% end %>
```

When i try to create a deal, with a pool and facility (in a single form), both deal and pool are created in the database. Nevertheless, the facility isn't created. What am i doing wrong?

Many thanks! :)

NB : do not take into account "facilityschedules". It'll be a 4th attribute once i have resolved this issue :)

Comment: Could be many things. Add your logs from the post and the form view code.

Comment: Hello Swards. Many thanks for you answer. :) I added those at the end of the initial post.

Comment: The error is in the logs - facilities is not a parameter.  You'll need to nest the form

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot :) Nevertheless, i don't find the solution. I just posted below what i modified in the _form.html.erb. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks again Swards!

Comment: I post the logs in a new answer. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not nesting facilities under pools.  Should be an easy fix, just nest facilities under pool.  Something like this will need to change.

```
<%= builder.fields_for :facilities do |fbuilder|%>
```

And it would need to be within the scope of the builder block.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, i added my new version of the block, but it doesn't work... could you please help me to solve that? :)

Comment: It all looks OK to me, so not sure.  Only thing I see missing is the id attribute in the form.  You'll need a hidden field if the record has an id.  I can't see how this would affect the submit.

Comment: For next steps, I'd try to figure out why the strong params is complaining about the facilities_attributes.  Add some logging to the create action to see what the params look like before and after the deal_params method is called.  I use the better_errors gem to help me debug, if you haven't tried it, it's very useful.

Comment: Swards thanks again for everything. It works now :)). You're my hero haha :)